# Smoothing scrollTop

Tags: javascript

I have this script that makes the header scroll up a bit when the user scroll the page and it is working fine. However, I want to make it scroll smoothly. I tried to do it myself, but I am not very good with java script.

```
<script>
window.onscroll=function () {
    var top = window.pageXOffset ? window.pageXOffset : document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;
    if(top > 50){document.getElementById("header").style.position = "fixed";
    document.getElementById("header").style.height="130px"
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById("header").style.position = "relative";
    document.getElementById("header").style.height="373px"
        }
}
</script>
```

Here is an example: [jsfiddle.net/largan/FDEJp](http://jsfiddle.net/largan/FDEJp)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: a js fiddle would do wonders to this mission!!!

Comment: here is it: http://jsfiddle.net/largan/FDEJp/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use `position:fixed` from the start. The browser is already doing a bunch of scrolling calculations for you so you definitely want to take advantage of that. The trick is to smoothly move the elements based on the position of the scroll. I'm using `margin-top` to position the content and `height` for the header. I have also cleaned up your markup to make better use of what the browser can already do. Notice I am moving the header and content separately, what his does is move the header in a more natural and intuitive way.

### Markup

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="header"> 
    header
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}    
#header {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  background: #880000;
  height: 203px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#content {
  margin-top: 203px;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
}
```

### JS

```
window.onscroll = function () {
  var doc = document.documentElement,
      body = document.body,
      top = (doc && doc.scrollTop  ||
        body && body.scrollTop  ||
        0);
  if(top < 75) {
    document
      .getElementById('header')
      .style
      .height = (203 - top * 2) + "px";
  }
  if(top < 130) {
    document
      .getElementById('content')
      .style
      .marginTop = (203 - top) + "px";
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FDEJp/2/

Comment: I checked your code in jsfiddle but for some reason it does not work

Comment: The only thing I can think of is I did get rid of the artificial `height` in your content. I can see you not seeing the effect if your viewport width is too big

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would use a fixed positioning for both cases.
The next thing I would do, is use a 'switch' instead of an 'if':

```
switch (top)
    {
        case 0:
            header.style.height="230px;
            break;
        case 1:
            header.style.height="228px";
            break;
        case 2:
            header.style.height="226px";
            break;
        case 3:
            header.style.height="224px";
            break;
        case 4:
            header.style.height="222px";
            break;
        case 5:
            header.style.height="220px";
            break;
        case 6:
            header.style.height="218px";
            break;
        case 7:
            header.style.height="216px";
            break;
        case 8:
            header.style.height="214px";
            break;
        case 9:
            header.style.height="212px";
            break;
        case 10:
            header.style.height="210px";
            break;
        case 11:
            header.style.height="208px";
            break;
        case 12:
            header.style.height="206px";
            break;
        case 13:
            header.style.height="204px";
            break;
        case 14:
            header.style.height="202px";
            break;
        case 15:
            header.style.height="200px";
            break;
        case 16:
            header.style.height="198px";
            break;
        case 17:
            header.style.height="196px";
            break;
        case 18:
            header.style.height="194px";
            break;
        case 19:
            header.style.height="192px";
            break;
        case 20:
            header.style.height="190px";
            break;
        default:
            header.style.height="130px";
            break;
    }
```

You can see that to make it easier for me to write, I changed the ending height to 130 px, so that for every '1 top' you scroll, the header will be shorter in 2 pixels.
I don't have time so I didn't finish the code and didn't check it too, but when you write it and make your adjustments, you should have 49 cases, I only wrote 20.

Comment: …what is this?! I'm just gonn'a say: `230 - (top * 2)`

Comment: Well, it's trivial: `header.style.height = (230 - top * 2) + 'px';`. You probably also want to throw a `Math.max` in there to limit it. If this stuff seems complicated, I *strongly* recommend following some beginner guides before jumping into your own projects.

Comment: How could i miss it haha